# Stackoverflow error with lombok in eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I am using Lombok 1.14.8, java 1.7 and eclipse Luna (using maven)

I keep getting this error in a pop-up:

"Lombok annotation handler class lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleData failed
java.lang.StackOverflowError"

followed by another pop-up to exit the workbench. It is very annoying. This was fine in my previous set-up, I just updated eclipse and lombok versions.

what version of lombok should I use to avoid this?

Comment: to answer my own question, this started working when I upgraded java version to 1.8.

Comment: this is still happening but not so frequently now, any solutions/suggestions?

Comment: Can you file a bug report at [the lombok issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/list)? Dicslosure: I am a Lombok developer.